# Cannot run webpack-encore on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, webpack-encore

I'm trying to use webpack-encore with symfony, but I'm having issues.
First I installed webpack-encore with composer:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
yarn install
```

When I try to run encore with:

```
node node_modules/.bin/encore production
```

I get this error:

```
C:\wamp64\www\symfony1\node_modules\.bin\encore:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:1
0)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_ma
in.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My OS is Windows 10, i believe that there is a problem with paths in Windows, but I don't know how to solve this issue. Can someone help me?

Comment: have you tried `yarn encore prod`?

Comment: Thank you a lot! This saved me a lot of time! :D

Comment: You're are welcome @Pietro Siccardi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using
`yarn encore prod`
for production environment
or
`yarn encore dev`
for development environment

For development, You can use also:
`yarn encore dev --watch`
If you want to recompile automatically your assets:

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack